# Many of the official links regarding the 2014 elections are dead

Tags: support, moderator-election

Related: [Is there a place where I can see information (the chats, Q&A, and results) for previous elections?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381115/1364007)

---

Something *weird* happened to the [2014 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5), and there are dead links aplenty.

- Dead links on the history of the [Election post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions):

  In [revision 18](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/18) of the [Election post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions), [Grace Note ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274402/grace-note) added:

  > - **[The candidates answer your questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire?cb=1)**

  then in [revision 19](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/19) of the post, [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) changed the link from meta.stackoverflow.com to meta.stackexchange.com:

  > - **[The candidates answer your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire?cb=1)**

  Both links (with post ID 221594) **are dead**.

  I searched, and found, the post here on meta.stackoverflow.com: [2014 SO Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299969/1364007) (post ID 299969).

---

- Dead links on the live [2014 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5) post:

  The 30 links above each of the candidates on the [2014 Election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5) are dead - taking [Bohemian ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) as an example:

  > [Bohemian's answers to your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222151)

  points to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222151 when it should point to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299993

---

- Dead links on the [Moderator Q&A post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299969/1364007):

  The 27<sup>*</sup> links on the Candidate Index on the [2014 SO Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299969/1364007) post are all dead - taking [Bohemian ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) as an example again, it says

  > [Bohemian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire#222151) ([nomination](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=nomination#post-21695065))

  so the link to the post in the Q&A is dead, but the link to the nomination is still alive. The link should point [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299993/1364007) (on Stack Overflow), not [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire#222151) (on Stack Exchange).

  <sup>*</sup> I'm aware that there are 30 nominations and 27 posts in the Q&A. I've not looked into it, but I am also aware that it's possible to nominate yourself but not answer the Q&A, and it's also possible to withdraw from the election process - presumably one (or both) of these are the reason.

---

What in the [Sam Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Hill_(euphemism)) is going on?

Comment: Why are you digging up old nominations? None of these people are running for re-election. Most of the questions are different. Of what interest is this archaeology?

Comment: @CodyGray - I don't have any agenda other than to satisfy my own curiosity: I'm not looking to ruffle any feathers by digging up the past, and if I am, I apologise. It's just that if the election pages are visible going back to their inception it's weird that, on a site where accuracy and correctness are highly valued, there are links to deleted posts on such (arguably) important parts of the site.

Comment: No, you're not ruffling any feathers. I'm just trying to understand, as you've had a flurry of activity on Meta recently regarding election matters of historical interest. Just wondering what the motivation is. The year 2014 is the year of [The Great Meta Schism](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/17/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/), when Meta Stack Overflow (MSO) and Meta Stack Exchange (MSE) were split apart. That's why some of the links are to MSE, and some are to MSO, and also why the Q&A appears both places, although it has been deleted on MSE by a moderator.

Comment: Regarding my activity - I've been spending more time than usual on Stack Overflow lately, doing research for my actual job. The election is very prominent in the side bar, so my interest was piqued. Thanks for the blog link - it answers my question.

Comment: 2014 is not that long ago. This is not "archaeology" and frankly I don't see the need for SO representatives to try to make people feel bad for bringing up issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a 10k+ user on MSE I can explain what happened.

The election happened in February 2014. Prior to April 2014, the site today known as Meta Stack Exchange *was* Meta Stack Overflow, with it serving as both the network-wide meta site *and* the per-site meta for Stack Overflow. However, at that time, the sites [were split](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/17/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/), with that site being renamed Meta Stack Exchange and a whole new per-site meta being set up for Stack Overflow. Also, at that time, SE ran a script to change all the old links to MSO to point to MSE, because it was still the same site but the domain name had changed.

At around July 2015, an SE employee used their dev powers to migrate this question to this site (bypassing the 60-day threshold). Normally, even after a migration stub gets deleted, it continues to redirect to the destination question on the other site; this includes dev migration after the 60-day threshold. However, in this case, it appears that the employee used [a special migration tool](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7411662#7411662) that immediately deletes the origin question and migrates the destination question without creating a migration history; according to that link, this was done to easily silently clean-up old SO-specific posts. The downside to that is that it doesn't result in a redirect.

Answer (score 14):

They're not dead; they're deleted.  Stack Exchange only soft-deletes records in general, so those of us with 10K+ on Meta Stack Exchange can see what's in those links.  Because you have less than 10K rep on MSE, you're not able to see them.

Comment: That's a bit weird. When you say deleted, is that due to migration? For instance, the link to [Bohemian ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian)'s answer at the of the question should point [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299993/1364007) (on Stack Overflow), not [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire#222151) (on Stack Exchange).

Comment: I meant to say "For instance, *I think* the link to...". As I am <10k on MSE I cannot see the contents.

Comment: _"They're not dead, they're just resting."_

Comment: @WaiHaLee:  I think you're right; a quick eyeball of those two posts tells me that they're very, very similar indeed.

Comment: Nothing suspicious here. This is the time of [The Great Meta Schism](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/17/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/).

Comment: It is somewhat unfortunate that many of the top voted posts before the migration were sent to MSE and deleted there mercilessly. They would have been very good reference posts if they had remained here. Some of them like the "Great Tag Cleanup of 2012" would have been really helpful.